# Parse JavaScript SDK subscription using containedIn

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to retrieved chats that a particular user is part of and that works but when I'm subscribing to that query and someone starts a chat me or I start a chat with a new person, it doesn't update. When I manually reload the page, it gets the latest chats so I think my query works but subscribing to it doesn't.

Here's my query:

```
let query = new Parse.Query("Chat");
query = query.containedIn("members", [Parse.User.current()]);
```

And here is the subscription:

```
let subscription = query.subscribe();
subscription.on("create", chat => addChatToView(chat))
```

I tried to do it manually by omitting the second line and subscribe to whole table and using `lodash` to somehow filter the results.

Is there any solution to this aside from doing it manually?

Comment: Have you followed the Parse Sever docs on [setting up live query](http://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#live-queries)?

Comment: Yes, I just forgot to mention it, but I did what Parse Server docs said. My other subscriptions like messages work.

Comment: Ok, It would be helpful if you could provide the code you've used to initialise a LiveQuery server and where you define the classes which should have LiveQuery enabled.

Comment: `liveQuery: { classNames: ["Chat","Message", "Location", "Book"] }`

It seems like it not about liveQuery but more like the query because I tried to subscribe to the table without `query.containedIn` and it worked

Comment: What version of Parse Server are you running?

Comment: I'm using v3.1.3

Comment: Ah, well I did find this issue about [using `containedIn` with live query](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/2088) but that has apparently been fixed since 2.6.3.

Comment: I tried to change my code to `query.equalTo("members", Parse.User.current())` but was not working as well.

Comment: Can you try query.equalTo("members", Parse.User.current().id) ?

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: I have the same Issue,  Someone can help?